# Windows 10 incorrect scaling or resolution on one display out of three

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've presently got three displays connected to Windows 10. My video cards are NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060. According to the Windows Advanced Display settings, all three displays are 1920x1080. However, it looks like one display, which is an LG TV, is actually a 'lower' resolution. When I move any app window to that display, it takes up a lot more of the screen space. But looking through any scaling settings I can find, it looks like everything is 100% scaling.

How can I resolve this discrepancy? Could the display be at a different resolution and not the claimed 1920x1080?

Comment: Telling us what the model of all 3 of your screens are would be helpful.

Comment: Did you make sure the display scaling and resolution setting is the same on all 3 monitors? https://www.pcworld.com/article/2953978/use-windows-10s-individual-display-scaling-to-perfect-your-multi-monitor-setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The issue was resolved by unplugging the HDMI cable from the graphics card, and plugging it back in. :-|
2. FYR the three displays are "HP S2231", "SAMSUNG", and "LG Electronics LG TV". Only the HP S2231 is a dedicated LCD display, the others are just 32 inch TVs. It was the LG that was the problem.
3. Before that, per Sickest answer, I had already verified that the NVIDIA control panel displayed "1080p, 1920 x 1080 (native)" in Display -> Change Resolution. (That's actually why I posted the question and I should have clarified I'd checked it there as well, not just in Windows).
4. Per what Appleoddity suggested in the article https://www.pcworld.com/article/2953978/use-windows-10s-individual-display-scaling-to-perfect-your-multi-monitor-setup.html, although I'd verified there the claimed resolution was 1920 x 180, in "Scale on layout" on that display, it was set to "150% (Recommended)". I simply didn't notice it, but it explained why apps were resizing when I moved them there.
5. While checking this out, I realized my Nvidia driver was much older than I'd realized. I had thought I had updated it before; 388.13, 430.4 is where they are at the moment with drivers for my cards.
6. Finally I was still perplexed about the claimed resolution, so I downloaded MonitorTest from Passmark. It unequivocally identified the resolution as "1280 x 720 - 32bpp - 60 Hertz". It was easier to see the larger pixels with it. So, it refused to run its visual tests at any higher resolution (don't remember if they were in the list). I plugged the HDMI cable into a different computer (a Windows 8.1 laptop) and got 1920 x 1080, as I expected. Then switching back, that's when 1920 x 180 showed up for reals.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You should not be using windows to control anything resolution related. You should be using the [Nvidia software](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/147182) to control that. When you finally do install (or update) the software, you will have way more control over each screen and what it can display.

Once opened you can goto Display > Resolution

Click on your each screen, and see the actual resolution and how it's even connected to your computer.

[image]

My guess is, one of your screen's isn't capable of 1080p resolution or your settings are wrong. And you should fix them in the nvidia software.